# How to create a matrix of paired values from two matrices?

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I have two matrices. They are,

```
m1={{a,b},{c,d}};
m2={{w,x},{y,z}};
```

I want to create a matrix of paired values that looks like this,

```
{{{a, w}, {b, x}}, {{c, y}, {d, z}}}
```

My equation for doing so looks like this,

```
Transpose /@ Transpose@{m1, m2}
```

and it works well; however, I thought I could use `Map` to accomplish the same thing at two different levels of the input. I have been unsuccessful in doing so. I have tried things like,

```
Map[Transpose, {m1, m2}, {0, 1}]
```

which results in,

```
{{{a, c}, {w, y}}, {{b, d}, {x, z}}}
```

which is clearly not what I want.

Is there a way to use `Map` in the above fashion and not call `Transpose` twice as I have done in the successful example?

P.S. I have seen this [example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180072/randomly-merge-elements-from-paired-lists-to-a-new-paired-list); however, the output format is incorrect for what I want. Yes, you could recreate the matrix dimensions with `Partition`; however, I am looking for a more minimal expression.

### Review of Answer Speeds

I reviewed the following answers for speed using `Timing`.

```
Timing[Flatten[{m1,m2},{{2},{3}}]]][[1]]
```

> ```
> (* 0.000021 *)
> ```

```
Timing[Transpose[{m1,m2},{3,1,2}]][[1]]
```

> ```
> (* 0.000038 *)
> ```

```
Timing[MapThread[List,{m1,m2},2]][[1]]
```

> ```
> (* 8.*10^-6 *)
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the edits @xzczd.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
MapThread[List, {m1, m2}, 2]
```

> `{{{a, w}, {b, x}}, {{c, y}, {d, z}}}`

More alternatives that yield the same answer:

```
Table[Transpose@{m1[[i]], m2[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[m1]}]
```

Comment: Works with `ArrayReshape[List@Flatten[{m1, m2}, {{2, 3}}], Array[2 &, 3]]`.

Comment: Hi, @bmf, I hope your move went well. Greetings.

Comment: @xzczd thanks for spotting that. Not sure how I missed it :/

Comment: @E.Chan-López still in the process of...paperwork is killing me

Comment: Thanks @bmf, I played with MapThread but did not use the List function and I ran into trouble with MapThread removing the Head. With Map, I tried keeping the Head using Head->True; however, that gave me strange results.
I think your answer best responds to the spirit of my question.

Comment: @desla.slade glad I was able to help :)

Comment: @bmf I have a doubt regarding the construction of certain types of pure functions. I asked a question in the community, in case you have any ideas about it. Greetings.

Answer (score 11):

Since particular use of `Transpose` is shown, let me show the particular use of `Flatten`:

```
Flatten[{m1, m2}, {{2}, {3}}]
```

To learn more about this syntax, check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14810/1871).

Comment: I'd accept this answer too if I could accept multiple answers.

Answer (score 10):

As long as it is symbolic:

```
(m1 + m2) /. Plus -> List
```

Or its twin brother:

```
m1 m2 /. Times -> List
```

---

Result:

> {{{a, w}, {b, x}}, {{c, y}, {d, z}}}

Answer (score 9):

Easier than using Map is to just use the other form of Transpose:

```
Transpose[{m1, m2}, {3, 1, 2}]
```

If you really wanted to do a Map-ish thing, MapThread might be easier:

```
MapThread[Transpose@*List, {m1, m2}]
```

Comment: (+1) nice to see that particular use of `Transpose`

Comment: Thanks @lericr. This is, I think, the most elegant answer. I played around with trying to move the different levels but my intuition for this is poor.

Comment: I'd accept this answer too if I could accept multiple answers.

Answer (score 7):

Just another way using `Outer`:

```
Table[Outer[List, m1, m2][[i, j, i, j]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]
(*{{{a, w}, {b, x}}, {{c, y}, {d, z}}}*)
```

Answer (score 7):

Riffing off of Syed's answer:

```
Function[{x, y}, {x, y}, Listable][m1, m2]
```

This started as

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable];
f[m1, m2] /. f -> List
```

Then I just turned it into an explicit function. This should avoid the problem Syed identified of needing to be symbolic.

**EDIT**

Okay, a bit more terse:

```
Function[, {##}, Listable][m1, m2]
```

Comment: (+1) Nice, Indeed!